# Why is this CheckBox not checked?

Tags: checkbox, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC ASP.Net Core website I'm writing and I've got a checkbox. I've spent hours thinking my binding was somehow wrong because I can save the value and it goes into the database but the view to the user always shows an unchecked checkbox. I finally had a look at the rendered HTML in Chrome Dev tools and this the checkbox:

```
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Show Profile Picture field is required." id="ShowProfilePic" name="ShowProfilePic" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

The value is true like it is in the database but in the browser the check box is unticked. The value it's looking at in the Model and ViewModel are both bool. Any ideas?

Comment: You should be using the `checked` attribute for a checkbox

Comment: Its the value of `ShowProfilePic` that determines if its checked or not. If its `true` (when you pass the model to the view in the GET method) then the checkbox will be checked, otherwise it wont. That is how model binding works (the method adds the `checked` attribute based on the value of the property)

Answer (score -3):

In ASP.NET, you should set the Checkbox control through the `Checked` attribute, so like:

```
checkBox.Checked = true;
```

That should then render it as checked on the browser. So you just use your boolean value from the database to set the `Checked` attribute.

Comment: OK I tried this: 
`@if (Model.ShowProfilePic)
                    {<input type="checkbox" asp-for="ShowProfilePic" class="form-inline LeftPadCheckBox" checked="checked" />}
                    else
                    {<input type="checkbox" asp-for="ShowProfilePic" class="form-inline LeftPadCheckBox" />}
                    <label asp-for="ShowProfilePic"></label>`

For some reason the @Model.ShowProfilePic is coming back as False even though I'm looking at the Database and it's definitely true (value of 1).

Comment: Checked my controller, wasn't setting the attribute on the model. dammit wasted so much time.

Comment: This is web forms code and has nothing to do with asp.net-core-mvc